# Getting right answer on console.log but return function not giving right answer

Tags: javascript

I am writing code for *Roman Numeral Converter* in the browser, currently learning Javascript. The problem is right on checking return statements in `console.log` I am getting the right answers, but somehow all tests are failing.

CODE:

```
let resstr = "";
let resarr = [];
function convertToRoman(num) {
  let robj = {
    M: 1000,
    CM: 900,
    D: 500,
    CD: 400,
    C: 100,
    XC: 90,
    L: 50,
    XL: 40,
    X: 10,
    IX: 9,
    V: 5,
    IV: 4,
    I: 1,
  };
  let okeys = Object.keys(robj); //getting keys for iteration

  //loop to check numbers and adding roman numerals in array
  okeys.some((key) => {
    if (num >= robj[key]) {
      //console.log(robj[key]);
      resarr.push(key);
      num = num - robj[key];
      //console.log("number after subtraction is: " + num);
      return true;
    }
  });

  //end cases
  if (num === 0) {
    resstr = resarr.join("").toString();
    console.log("operation done", resstr);
    return resstr;
  } else if (num !== 0) {
    console.log("no 0", num);
    return convertToRoman(num);
  } else {
    console.log("ended");
    return true;
  }
  // console.log(resstr);
  // return resstr;
}
```

For `convertToRoman(3999)`, `convertToRoman(1)`, `convertToRoman(2)` etc. I am getting the right answers on `console.log`, but browser tests are all failing like it is getting something else than the right answer.

Comment: While your code needs improvements to make it cleaner, it is currently working properly, to make sure, try `const result = convertToRoman(3999); console.log(result)` it will log `MMMCMXCIX`, _but browser tests are all failing_ what type of testing do you mean? are you trying to solve some code challenges in some websites like _leetcode_? sometimes they need the solution in a specific way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try refactoring your function to avoid using global variables to store intermediate results (`resstr` and `resarr`). Using global variables like this can cause issues in the context of running multiple tests in sequence since they would retain their values from previous calls across tests, leading to incorrect results.

Here is an arguably easier-to-read way of solving this problem that doesn't use global variables to store intermediate results:

```js
// NOTE: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation = .
//       This naming style reads left to right and therefore continues
//       to be easy to grok at a glance for more nested maps as well.
const VALUE_BY_ROMAN_NUMERAL = {
  M: 1000, CM: 900, D: 500, CD: 400, C: 100, XC: 90, 
  L: 50, XL: 40, X: 10, IX: 9, V: 5, IV: 4, I: 1,
};

/**
 * Converts a given number into its Roman numeral representation.
 * 
 * @param {number} num - The number to convert to a Roman numeral.
 * @returns {string} The Roman numeral representation of the given number.
 */
function convertToRoman(num) {
  let result = "";
  for (const [romanNumeral, value] of Object.entries(VALUE_BY_ROMAN_NUMERAL)) {
    while (num >= value) {
      result += romanNumeral;
      num -= value;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(convertToRoman(3999));
console.log(convertToRoman(1));
console.log(convertToRoman(2));
```